# Print value without double square brackets python

Tags: python, brackets

I'm trying to print a value without the double square brackets in python. Say I have

```
a = [[2]]
```

and I want to print the value into a textfile or whatnot. With

```
print(a)
```

I of course get

```
[[2]]
```

I tried

```
 print(np.asarray(a))
 print(str(a))
 print("" . join(str(a)))
```

all these commands return the same as above. How can I print the value without brackets?

Comment: If you want to get the element from your nested list, it's `a[0][0]`. Otherwise, not clear what you're after.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[2]]` is a list containing a list containing the number 2.

To get the first element from a list, use `a[0]`.

To get the first element from a list and then the first element of that, use `a[0][0]`.

Answer (score 3):

using a[0][0], for example if a = [1,[2,3]]

```
a[1][1]
```

this gives you 3

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer is given in the comments below your question, this will just give you some idea on indexing. What you have is an integer value as a sublist within the list.

```
a = [[2]]
```

If you print its length and type

```
print (len(a), type(a))
```

you get

```
1 <class 'list'>
```

which means your `a` is a list with length 1. Since in python, indexing starts from `0`, the content of list `a` is accessed as `a[0]`. But now repeating the above step again,

```
print (len(a[0]), type(a[0]))
```

yields

```
1 <class 'list'>
```

which means the sublist `a[0]` is itself a `list` of length 1 and the content of this sublist `a[0]` can be accessed using the index `0`. This means `0` index of `a[0]` as `a[0][0]`. This can go on forever depending on the number of sublists. But eventually the integer inside will result in `TypeError` because integer has no length.

```
print (len(a[0][0]))
```

yields

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Hope you understood the gist behind all this sublist and indexing.